# How can I set a literal JSON value in AWS CDK with Java?

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I have to set a literal JSON value to define the home directory mapping of a user in Java based CDK definition:

```
    CfnUser user1 = CfnUser.Builder.create(this, "user1 ")
        .userName("user1")
        .serverId(transferServer.getAttrServerId())
        .homeDirectoryType("PATH")
        .homeDirectory("/path/to/home")
        .homeDirectoryMappings(List.of("Entry:/", "Target:/path/to/home"))
        .role(role.getRoleArn())
        .build();
```

The above code fails, because the `List` passed to `homeDirectoryMappings()` is not a `software.amazon.awscdk.IResolvable`. Somehow I have to create a `IResolvable` which represents this JSON:

```
[
   {
      "Entry":"/",
      "Target":"/bucket3/customized-reports/"
   }
]
```

I searched throuth the implementations of `IResolvable` but cannot find a suitable class.

So how can I pass a JSON literal to a method that takes a `IResolvable`?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the error message one more time I noticed, that the `homeDirectoryMappings()` method accepts a `List` of `HomeDirectoryMapEntryProperty` instances. So there's actually no need for a `IResolvable`.

So the correct code lookes like this:

```
    CfnUser user1 = CfnUser.Builder.create(this, "user1 ")
        .userName("user1 ")
        .serverId(transferServer.getAttrServerId())
        .homeDirectoryType("LOGICAL")
        .homeDirectoryMappings(List.of(new HomeDirectoryMapEntryProperty.Builder()
            .entry("/")
            .target("/s3-bucket/home/${transfer:UserName}")
            .build())
        )
        .role(dlRole.getRoleArn())
        .build();
```